# Find a general solution to the ODE $y'' - 3y' +2y = 10\sin(x) + 2\cos(2x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

Hello I've been trying to do this question for a bit but I'm not too sure how to proceed or apply the concept to this question. Any clues or hints please? Thank you!

Comment: The solution can be written as a complementary function plus a particular integral. See if you can work out either.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  This is a linear differential equation.  Do you know how to solve $y''-3y'+2y=0$?

Comment: Please insert the own thoughts, the progress made to solve the problem and where is the point where things got stuck. It is the way it works, and moreover potential answers will have a better chance to get straight to that point. Note that writing down the own thoughts is a fist big step in the direction of a solution.

Comment: Thank you everyone and for the warm welcome! I managed to have it solved in the end :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the general solution is
$$y=y_h+y_c$$
The homogeneous solution:
$$r^2-3r+2=0$$
$$r=1,r=2$$
so
$$y_h=c_1e^x+c_2e^{2x}$$
Complementary Solution :

let $$y_c=A\sin x+B\cos x+C\sin2x+D\cos2x$$
now drive it two times and substitute the equations in the original differential equation to get the constants

Comment: Thanks for your hints! I managed to get it solved in the end :) should I post my solutions or something...?

Comment: if you want to check your solution, send it here to see if it is right or not.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

I would start by noticing that
\begin{align*}
y'' - 3y' + 2y = 10\sin(x) + 2\cos(2x) & \Longleftrightarrow (y'' - y') - 2(y' - y) = 10\sin(x) + 2\cos(2x)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (y' - y)' - 2(y' - y) = 10\sin(x) + 2\cos(2x)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow z' - 2z = 10\sin(x) + 2\cos(2x)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (e^{-2x}z)' = 10e^{-2x}\sin(x) + 2e^{-2x}\cos(2x)
\end{align*}
Then you integrate both sides and apply the integrating factor once again.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm pretty stiff when it comes to math so I'm not able to understand the stuff you said but I managed to have it solved in the end :)